# Lining up link buttons to be centered in between the links above them

Tags: html, css

I have a total of five link buttons three on top and two underneath. I am trying to get them to line up by having the bottom two links centered inbetween the ones on top. Currently there is a big gap inbetween them. Can someone help me adjust the css to line up directly inbetween the ones above them?

```css
.content-sm {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
* {
    border-radius: 0;
}


/*Business Posts Section
------------------------------------*/
.business-post-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}


/*Business Posts Links/Buttons
------------------------------------*/
.business-post-link {
 padding-top: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

.business-post-link i {
 color: #fff;
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
 padding: 30px;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 background: #00539c;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.business-post-link i:after {
 top: -8px;
 left: -8px;
 right: -8px;
 bottom: -8px;
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
 border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-link:hover i,
.business-post-link:hover i:after {
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.business-post-link:hover i {
 background: #db9e33;
}

.business-post-link:hover i:after {
 border-color: #db9e33;
}

.rounded-x {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-title {
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #555;
}
  

@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
} 
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9 {
    float: left;
} 
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--=== Business Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
  <div class="container content-sm">
   <div class="row ">
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-drawer"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Tax Collection Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-flag"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Auction Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-wallet"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Payment Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
  </div>
  
  <!--=== Contact Us Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
  <div class="container content-sm">
   <div class="row ">
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-6 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-screen-desktop"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Request a Demo</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-6 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-call-in"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Contact Us</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
  </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: check out flexbox for this kind of thing. It really makes things like centering very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try putting some col-md-2 place holder divs on either side?

The first row of three buttons, since all three divs are `col-md-4` in a 12 column system, the top row of buttons end up centered between columns 2 & 3, between 6 & 7, and between 10 & 11.

The ideal place to center the two buttons for the second row would be between columns 4 & 5 and between columns 8 & 9.  But if you do two big col-md-3 columns, they end up getting centered between columns 3 & 4 and between columns 9 & 10.

```css
.content-sm {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
* {
    border-radius: 0;
}


/*Business Posts Section
------------------------------------*/
.business-post-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}


/*Business Posts Links/Buttons
------------------------------------*/
.business-post-link {
 padding-top: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

.business-post-link i {
 color: #fff;
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
 padding: 30px;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 background: #00539c;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.business-post-link i:after {
 top: -8px;
 left: -8px;
 right: -8px;
 bottom: -8px;
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
 border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-link:hover i,
.business-post-link:hover i:after {
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.business-post-link:hover i {
 background: #db9e33;
}

.business-post-link:hover i:after {
 border-color: #db9e33;
}

.rounded-x {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.business-post-title {
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #555;
}
  

@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
} 
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9 {
    float: left;
} 
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--=== Business Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
  <div class="container content-sm">
   <div class="row ">
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-drawer"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Tax Collection Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-flag"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Auction Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-wallet"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Payment Solutions</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
  </div>
  
  <!--=== Contact Us Block ===-->
  <div class="business-post-section">
  <div class="container content-sm">
   <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-screen-desktop"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Request a Demo</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.test.com">
    <div class="col-md-4 business-post-link">
     <i class="rounded-x icon-call-in"></i>
     <h2 class="business-post-title">Contact Us</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
  </div>
    
    </div>
```